# Creating a numpy matrix from given min and max priors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have 3 priors given minimum and maximum ranges. By using them, I need to create a NumPy array in the form of;

`M = [[x_0, y_0, z_0], [x_1, y_1, z_1], ...,[x_N, y_N, z_N]]`

where `x=[0.60, 0.80]`, `y=[1, 80]`, `z=[0.022, 0.024]` how can I do this in a most efficient way (i.e., by least amount of code and by using NumPy) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be achieved by:

```
np.array([x, y, z]).T
```

some benchamrks:

```
size = 3 * 1000
50 loops, best of 5: 8.14 µs per loop     # np.vstack
50 loops, best of 5: 2.95 µs per loop     # this answer

size = 3 * 10000
50 loops, best of 5: 27.3 µs per loop
50 loops, best of 5: 19.9 µs per loop

size = 3 * 100000
50 loops, best of 5: 383 µs per loop
50 loops, best of 5: 359 µs per loop

size = 3 * 1000000
50 loops, best of 5: 5.23 ms per loop
50 loops, best of 5: 5.09 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

N = 4
xs = np.random.uniform(x[0], x[1], size=N)
ys = np.random.uniform(y[0], y[1], size=N)
zs = np.random.uniform(z[0], z[1], size=N)

res = np.vstack((xs,ys,zs)).transpose()
```

Example with numbers

```py
N = 4
xs = np.random.uniform(0.6, 1.1, size=N)
ys = np.random.uniform(3, 5, size=N)
zs = np.random.uniform(8, 9, size=N)
res = np.vstack((xs,ys,zs))
res.transpose()
# array([[0.88860867, 3.11233047, 8.26189772],
#        [0.70096631, 4.984737  , 8.01999442],
#        [1.08111807, 3.54934757, 8.28137655],
#        [1.04116942, 3.16903737, 8.12647381]])
```